# Latex error appearing from nowhere

Tags: errors, compilation-error

When compiling my latex file I'm getting the following error message:

```
./main.aux|1 error| Text line contains an invalid character. ^^@
./main.aux|1 error| Text line contains an invalid character. ^^@^^@
./main.aux|1 error| Text line contains an invalid character. ^^@^^@^^@
./main.aux|1 error| Text line contains an invalid character. ^^@^^@^^@^^@
./main.aux|1 error| Text line contains an invalid character. ^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@
./main.aux|1 error| Text line contains an invalid character. ^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@^^@
```

and the above many times. The weird thing is that this seems to have occurred out of nowhere since I haven't changed the file since the last time I have compiled it and at that point it would still work fine. Also, the error message isn't really helpful so I can't locate the source of the error. Has somebody maybe already experienced a similar issue and could give me some advice? Thanks in advance!

I have already deleted all my auxiliary files (including the `.aux` file) but this didn't change anything. In my log file it says a the above weird symbols have occurred in my `.aux` file, but at the respective line I only find

```
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {5}
{\ignorespaces understimated area}}{19}{figure.5}\protected@file@percent }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Without seeing any code it is hard to help you ...

Comment: @Mensch The problem is that my file contains over 3500 lines, so it would probably not help much if I provided it.

Comment: Copy your tex file, call it mwe.tex or simular, and start to make it shorter but still resulting in your issue. Show us the shortest tex file you can create resulting in your issue. Its calles an MWE, an minimal working example ...

Comment: The error message you quote hasn't the standard form of TeX errors. What are you using to run `tex`?

Comment: It is very weird, I have recompiled my program several times without changing anything, and now it seems to work. I'm using latexmk.

Comment: the errors are ASCII NULL (byte zero) in the aux file, you can simply delete that file. You can not get that error if you have delted the aux file.

Comment: the aux file is re-written each time so it is not unexpected that such an error will clear itself by forcing a re-run of latex.

Comment: I just saw that in a project. There the aux-file got corrupted as the guy had a NAS system which synched files while they were written.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hm, the OP already said that they tried deleting the aux file.

Comment: Then in that case... try to make sure that you deleted the *correct* aux file. output-directory or TeX's current directory might be somewhere else. (copy only the TeX file to a different folder and compile that)

Comment: @user202729 sure but the error message related to an undeleted aux file.